# How can I manually trigger re-execution of a shared py.test fixture?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Say I have a fixture which I want to share for most of my tests:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def account():
   # create a new account
```

But now in one of the tests, I want to override the `scope='session'` bit and actually have the fixture re-execute (create a new account). Is there a way to tell the fixture to "override the cache/memoization" just for one test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply calling the fixture manually from the test will cause it to re-execute. e.g.

```
def test_foo():
    new_account = account()
```

Comment: FWIW, this feature is deprecated: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to find out the answer to your question, I think your problem can be solved more easily. Just factor out account creation to another function and write two fixtures:

```
def create_account():
    return 'account'

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def account():
    return create_account()

@pytest.fixture(scope='something else'):
def another_account():
    return create_account()
```